# JFrame not painting rectangle

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paint

Have a very simple issue which I haven't come across before. I used a similar layout before when doing a project.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class q1
{
    public static void main (String Args [])
    {
        q1Window showMe = new q1Window();
    }
}

class q1Window
{
    q1Window()
    {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Tutorial 1");
        window.setSize(600,600);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void paint (Graphics back)
    {
        back.setColor(Color.black);
        back.fillRect(30,30,100,200);           
    }
}
```

Now I can't seem to print anything however the JFrame shows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't just add a paint() method to any class. Only Swing components have painting methods.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

Quick summary is that you need to override the `paintComponent()` method of a JPanel and then add the panel to the frame.

Answer (score -2):

As camickr pointed out, you need a Swing component to do what you want, which in this case, is to override `paint()`, although you should be overriding `paintComponent()` instead.

Try this:

```
class q1 {

    public static void main(String Args[]) {
        q1Window showMe = new q1Window();
    }
}

class q1Window extends JFrame {

    q1Window() {
        setTitle("Tutorial 1");
        setSize(600, 600);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics back) {
        back.setColor(Color.black);
        back.fillRect(30, 30, 100, 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 for overriding `paint` of a top level container, -1 for failing to call `super.paint` and breaking the paint chain, not to mention intial threads

Comment: -1, this is a terrible example.  @bobski, this is NOT the way to learn how to program. Just because it is only a few changes to your existing code does not mean you should use the suggestion. The proper approach has already been given  I suggest you read the tutorial link you were given and learn the basics.

Comment: Well, it is my bad that I didn't use ANY of the mentioned best practices. In no way this is the recommended way. I just posted a little something that works in this case.