# java counter repaints on the previous number

Tags: java, user-interface, counter

Basically I'm using a action listener to simply increment a number by one every second. I'm using a timer and the jlabel for this to work. Currently the numbers go up..1...2....3 and so on however it repaints over itself so the number 2 will show above 1 for example. I tried moving my paint method inside the actionlistener class however had no luck. Would someone be willing to see where I am going wrong?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class six1
{   
    public static void main (String Args[])
    {
        frame adam = new frame();

    }
}

class frame extends JFrame
{
    int counter = 0;
    frame()
    {
        setSize(1000,1000);
        setTitle("Adam,");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        AL a = new AL();
        Timer t1 = new Timer(1000, a);
        t1.start();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawString("" + counter, 500, 500);
    }

    class AL implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
        {
            counter++;
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you overriding paint(). Did you not read the answer in your last question - (http://stackoverflow.com/q/20620144/131872). It was specifically stated you should override the paintComonent() method!!!  And if you actually read the tutorial you would have found a working example that shows you how to draw text. It gets annoying when you waste peoples time because you don't listen to advice that has already been given.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm using a timer and the jlabel for this to work.

You are not using a JLabel, you are doing custom painting.

The question is why are you doing custom painting? The better solution would be to use a JLabel and then just use the `setText(...)` method and let the label manage the painting.

Also, if you do use custom painting, then you should be overriding the `paintComponent()` method, not the paint() method.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to call `super.paint(Graphics)`:

```
public void paint (Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(Graphics);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.drawString("" + counter, 500, 500);
}
```

Comment: +1 for answering the question. -1 for not suggesting the proper way to do custom painting is to override the paintComponent() method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of repainting every few seconds, you could just setText on the label.